# Why GSM do challenge-response authencation before encryption?

Tags: authentication, gsm

I read [this Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_procedures) and I can't understand, why GSM do challenge-response authencation before encryption? Why it doesn't start encryption at the beggining and authencate with it?

Why this:

- MS sends its IMSI to operator
- Operator check IMSI and sends correspoinding RAND
- MS make response and Kc with RAND and Ki, store the Kc and sends the response to operator
- Operator check the response and send info about used encryption protocol etc to MS
- And now all communication will be encrypted with Kc

Instead of this:

- MS sends its IMSI to operator
- Operator check IMSI and sends correspoinding RAND
- MS make Kc with RAND and Ki, store the Kc and starts encrypt all communication with the Kc
- Operator decrypt all communication with Kc and if decrypted content is ok, authencation is done

Comment: There might be a real answer to this but most likely it's simply *there's no need for encryption before the MS is authenticated*.

Comment: Yes, but my point is, why is separate authencation needed? Encryption with Kc do authencate as well, right?